# Every affine variety in $\mathbb A^n$ consisting of finitely many points can be written as the zero locus of $n$ polynomials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra

I am reading Gathmann's free online notes on Algebraic Geometry. One exercise asks to show that

> "Every affine variety in $\mathbb A^n$ consisting of finitely many points can be written as the zero locus of $n$ polynomials".

There is a hint says "interpolation". I don't know how to start with the hint.

If $n=2$, we can use interpolation to get 1 polynomial for finitely many points. But we need to show 2 polynomials instead. I am also not sure how to apply interpolation for higher dimensions. Anyone can help? Thank you!

Comment: The famous Nullstellensatz of Hilbert assure this in a more general context

Comment: @Piquito What do you mean specifically?

Comment: @Daianne'deSouza.- **Nullstellensazt**: Let $k$ be a field  and $K$ be its algebraic closure . Consider the polynomial ring ${\displaystyle k[X_{1},\ldots ,X_{n}]}$  and let $I$ be an ideal in this ring. The algebraic set $V(I)$ defined by this ideal consists of all n-tuples $x = (x_1,...,x_n)\in K^n$  such that $f(x) = 0$ for all $f\in I$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume that the points are $a_k=(a_k^{1},a_k^2,...,a_k^n)$, for $k=1,2,...,M$.

We can use the following system

$$\begin{cases}0&=\prod_{k=1}^{M}(z_1-a_k^1)\\
0&=\prod_{k=1}^{M}(z_2-a_k^2)+\\&+\sum_{j=1}^{M}\left[\frac{(-1)^j\prod_{k=1,k\neq j}^{M}(z_1-a_k^1)}{\prod_{k=1,k\neq j}^{M}(a_j-a_k)}\cdot(z_2-a_j^2)\cdot\left\{\prod_{k=1,k\neq j}^{M}(z_2-a_k^2)+1\right\}\right]\\
...\\
0&=\prod_{k=1}^{M}(z_n-a_k^n)+\\&+\sum_{j=1}^{M}\left[\frac{(-1)^j\prod_{k=1,k\neq j}^{M}(z_1-a_k^1)}{\prod_{k=1,k\neq j}^{M}(a_j-a_k)}\cdot(z_n-a_j^n)\cdot\left\{\prod_{k=1,k\neq j}^{M}(z_n-a_k^n)+1\right\}\right]\end{cases}$$

The first polynomial forces the possible values for $z_1$ as $a_1^1,a_2^1,...,a_N^1$. The role of the other polynomials is to force the values of the other variables according to the value of $z_1$.

The equations are symmetric by permutations on the index $k$. Assume without loss of generality that $z_1$ is, say $=a_1^1$. Then the $r$-th equation, for $r=2,3,...,n$, becomes

$$\begin{align}0&=\prod_{k=1}^{M}(z_r-a_k^r)-(z_r-a_1^r)\cdot\left\{\prod_{k=1,k\neq j}^{M}(z_r-a_k^r)+1\right\}\\&=(z_r-a_1^r)\end{align}$$

from where $z_r$ is forced to be $=a_1^r$.

Comment: I believe there is some typo in the denominators, there should be $a_{j}^{1} - a_{k}^{1}$. However, how do you ensure that it is non-zero? I guess it can happen that two distinct points have the same first coordinate....

Comment: @JanVysoky, you are right. Some $\textbf{lazy}$ people do not accept edits to this post :( Moreover, choosing another $z_1$ does not change the sign, so the multiplication by $(-1)^j$ is wrong. The last equality is also incorrect. It must be $0 = -(z_r - a_1^r)$. 

However, the idea is nice. 1) When $K$ is algebraically closed, then we can "rotate" the axes, so that the first coordinates of all points are different.

Comment: 2) If $K$ is not algebraically closed, we need only one polynomial. For any point $a_i$ there is a polynomial $f_i \in K[x_1, \dots , x_n]$ with exactly one root, namely $f_i(a_i) = 0$. Then $f = f_1 f_2 \cdots f_M $ has $\{ a_1, \dots, a_M \}$ as only solution.

Answer (score 8):

We use induction on $n$, the base case $n=1$ being trivial (note that the result is actually false for $n=0$; alternatively you can require the varieties to be nonempty and take $n=0$ as the base case).

Now suppose the result is known for $n$ and let $V\subseteq \mathbb{A}^{n+1}$ be finite.  Let $a_1,\dots,a_m$ be all the different first coordinates of points of $V$ and let $V_i=\{b\in \mathbb{A}^n:(a_i,b)\in V\}$.  By the induction hypothesis, for each $i$ we can choose $n$ polynomials $f_{i1},\dots,f_{in}$ whose vanishing set is $V_i$.  For $1\leq k\leq n$, we can then choose a polynomial $g_k$ in $n+1$ variables such that $g_k(a_i,y)=f_{ik}(y)$ for each $i$ (here $y$ is an $n$-tuple of variables). Explicitly, if $e_i(x)$ is a polynomial in one variable that is $1$ on $a_i$ and $0$ on $a_j$ for $j\neq i$, then you can take $g_k(x,y)=\sum_i e_i(x)f_{ik}(y)$.  Finally, we see that $V$ is the vanishing set of the polynomials $g_1(x,y),\dots,g_n(x,y)$ together with one more $(x-a_1)\dots(x-a_m)$.

Comment: Apologies for commenting on an old post, but I have a question: when you are reading a mathematics book or paper, do you have to consciously think about whether the theorem statements are true for trivial cases like $\mathbb A^0$, or say, the empty set? Or do you just automatically pick up whether the statement is true for the trivial cases as you are scanning through all the cases? Sorry if my question isn't clear.

Comment: Generally they should be true in all stated cases, but sometimes there are errors and minor edge cases are overlooked.  I don't think it's something I would usually be actively looking out for, but I often notice it because the simplest cases are often where I would start when trying to understand a theorem.

Answer (score 2):

To simplify exposition, let's say $n=3$ and the points are $p_i = (x_i, y_i, z_i)$ ($1\leq i\leq n$). Let's assume that all $x_i$ are distinct - since we only have finitely many points we can always find a linear transformation of the plane that makes this true.

Let the first polynomial be $P_x := \prod_i (x-x_i)$. The zero locus of this polynomial are the points that agree with some $p_i$ in the first coordinate. Now consider the set of points $(x_i, y_i) \subset\mathbb{R}^2$, and use [Lagrange interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) to find some polynomial $P_y$ such that for all $i$, $P_y(x_i) = y_i$. Our second polynomial will then be $P_y(x) - y$.

Note that if we have a point on which $P_x$ vanishes, then $x$ is one of the $x_i$ in our set of points, and $P_y(x)-y = P_y(x_i) - y = y_i - y = 0$ if and only if $y = y_i$. We can similarly construct a polynomial $P_z$ to enforce $x = x_i \implies z = z_i$. Note that the construction of $P_y$ and $P_z$ are independent so in fact this construction generalizes to any $n$ (it's just that the notation for the general case would have become a bit cumbersome).