# Finite variety and its "vanishing ideal"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra

Here is a problem from Ernst Kunz's *Introduction to Commutative Algebra and Algebraic Geometry*:

Let $K$ be an infinite field, $V \subset \mathbb{A}^n(K)$ a finite set of points. It's ideal $\mathfrak{J}(V)$ in $K[X_1, ..., X_n]$ is generated by $n$ polynomials. Hint: Interpolation.

note: 
$\mathfrak{J}(V)$ consists of all $F \in K[X_1, ..., X_n]$ with $F(x) = 0$ for all $x\in V$

A similar question can be found in [enter link description here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1098010/every-affine-variety-in-mathbb-an-consisting-of-finitely-many-points-can-be). The solutions given above are not complete and satisfying. I've tried some simple cases: $n = 1$ and $V$ is a single point. For other cases, I don't have any accessible solutions.

Anyone can help? Prefect the solution in the link or give an alternative approach to the problem. Thank you!