# a finite variety and its "vanishing ideal"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra

Here is a problem from Ernst Kunz's *Introduction to Commutative Algebra and Algebraic Geometry*:

Let $K$ be an infinite field, $V \subset \mathbb{A}^n(K)$ a finite set of points. It's ideal $\mathfrak{J}(V)$ in $K[X_1, ..., X_n]$ is generated by $n$ polynomials. Hint: Interpolation.

note: 
$\mathfrak{J}(V)$ consists of all $F \in K[X_1, ..., X_n]$ with $F(x) = 0$ for all $x\in V$

A similar question can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1098010/every-affine-variety-in-mathbb-an-consisting-of-finitely-many-points-can-be). The solutions given above just answers why any finite variety can be writen as the zero locus of n polynomials. But further questions: do the n polynomials constructed in the link generate the vanishing ideal? And that's my question really concerned. Is the condition "the field K infinite" necessary? How do we use it? I've tried some simple cases: $n = 1$ and $V$ is a single point. For other cases, I don't have any accessible solutions.

Anyone can help? Prefect the solution in the link or give an alternative approach to the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The inductive proof I gave at the linked question works to get functions which generate $\mathfrak{I}(V)$ (and it is not necessary for $K$ to be infinite).  Specifically, letting $a_1,\dots,a_m$ be all the different first coordinates of points of $V$, note that $$K[x,y_1,\dots,y_n]/((x-a_1)\dots(x-a_m))\cong \prod_{i=1}^m K[y_1,\dots,y_n]$$ by the Chinese remainder theorem (with the map being given by evaluation at the $a_i$) and so $$K[x,y_1,\dots,y_n]/((x-a_1)\dots(x-a_m), g_1(x,y),\dots,g_n(x,y)) \cong\prod_{i=1}^m K[y_1,\dots,y_n]/(g_1(a_i,y),\dots,g_n(a_i,y)).$$ So if, by the induction hypothesis, you choose $g_1,\dots,g_n$ such that the polynomials $g_k(a_i,y)=f_{ik}(y)$ for $1\leq k\leq n$ generate the ideal $\mathfrak{I}(V_i)$ for $V_i=\{b\in\mathbb{A}^n(K):(a,b)\in V\}$ for each $i$ from $1$ to $n$, then $$K[x,y_1,\dots,y_n]/((x-a_1)\dots(x-a_m), g_1(x,y),\dots,g_n(x,y))$$ will end up isomorphic to a product of copies of $K$, one for each point of $V$ (with the isomorphism given by evaluation at those points).  This shows that $$((x-a_1)\dots(x-a_m), g_1(x,y),\dots,g_n(x,y))=\mathfrak{I}(V),$$ since each side is the kernel of the evaluation map $K[x,y_1,\dots,y_n]\to K^V$.

Answer (score 0):

For $a_1,\ldots,a_M \in \overline{K}^N$ our ideal is $$J = I(\{a_1,\ldots,a_m\}) = \bigcap_m I(\{a_m\})$$

$K[X_1,\ldots,X_N]/J$ is a product of fields because it is finite dimensional $K$-algebra and it contains no nilpotent element : if $f$ doesn't vanish on all the $a_m$ then so does $f^r$.

Let $J_n = J \cap K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$. Then $K[X_1,\ldots,X_{n}]/J_n$ is a product of fields because it is a $K$-subalgebra of $K[X_1,\ldots,X_N]/J$.

For each maximal ideal $\mathfrak{M}_{n,l}$ of $K[X_1,\ldots,X_{n}]/J_n$ then $(K[X_1,\ldots,X_{n}]/J_n / \mathfrak{M}_{n,l})[X_{n+1}]$  is a one-variable polynomial ring over a field so in that ring $J_{n+1}$ is principal generated by $f_{n+1,l}(X_1,\ldots,X_{n+1})$,

and since the $\mathfrak{M}_{n,l}$ are comaximal there is some polynomial $F_{n+1}(X_1,\ldots,X_{n+1})$ which is $\equiv f_{n+1,l}(X_1,\ldots,X_{n+1}) \bmod \mathfrak{M}_{n,l}$ for each $l$ so that $J_{n+1} = (J_n,F_{n+1}(X_1,\ldots,X_{n+1}))$ and $$J = (F_1(X_1),\ldots,F_N(X_1,\ldots,X_N))$$

Comment: The point of the question is to show that, independent of the finite set of points, you only need as many generators for the ideal as the dimension of the ambient space. You lose control of the generators as soon as you take an intersection.

Comment: @Stephen Tks I tried an argument